# How can i run my ruby service with chef recipe

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a web service in ruby, and i want to run my ruby service via chef recipe.
I have used execute command as :

```
execute 'start-ruby' do
command 'ruby /opt/certificate.rb start'
action :run
end
```

I can see my ruby service running in background on my Amazon instance, but somehow Instance setup is stuck in running setup.
Is there any other alternative from which i can run my ruby service via chef recipe.

Answer (score 0):

The execute resource runs its command synchronously, meaning it waits for it to finish before continuing with the recipe. I'm guessing your `start` command there starts a foreground-mode daemon (which is how it should work) so it never returns and Chef just waits forever.

Check out https://github.com/poise/application_examples/blob/master/recipes/todo_rails.rb or https://github.com/poise/poise-service for examples of Ruby application deployment and generic service management respectively.